# what is the use of the below function in PHP?

Tags: php

What is the use of the function in PHP?

```
public function processApi()

{

 $func = strtolower(trim(str_replace("/","",$_REQUEST['rquest'])));

   ( (int)method_exists($this,$func) > 0 ) ? $this->$func() : $this->response('',404); 

   // If the method not exist with in this class, response would be "Page not found".

}
```

Comment: if function exists in the same class run it or display 404 page.
very vulnerable indeed.

Answer (score 0):

`$_REQUEST` contains content of `$_GET, $_POST, and $_COOKIE.`

So basically you are reading the method name passed from client and checking if it exists in particular context / class.

If function is present, code is executing the function and if not found its returning 404.

However, this is vulnerable as it exposes methods and any user may invoke them remotely.

Comment: Thanks for your kind and useful reply